# How to give a user account root privileges in Fedora 14?

Tags: linux, root, fedora-14

I want to give my user account root access rights permanently, how can I do that?

I don't want to log in using the root account.

Answer (score 2):

Go to System Settings » Users » Click on the keylock button. You will be asked to enter the root password. Here, change your group from *standard* to *administrator*. From now on you can use `sudo`.

If you want to do it the command line way, follow [this](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/how-to-add-a-user-to-the-sudoers-list/) link. Enter `visudo` in a root terminal. Under the following line:

```
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Enter:

```
user ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Save by pressing <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd>.